# BOOST::thread worker syncronization, C++ & OpenCV

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, boost

I'm working on a project where i'm parallelizing an object tracker written in OpenCV, adapting it to track multiple objects.
I'm doing the multithreading part using the BOOST library, which has a very clean interface for portable multithreading.

I have multiple instances of the tracking function running over multiple threads, spawned depending on the number of objects detected in the initial scene. Every thread has it's own working loop where, frame by frame, he tracks the object. My question is: how do i gather up results at each loop iteration so i can save them? There is no communication between threads, but at the end of each loop, when a frame processing is done, I wish to sum the outputs of each thread so I can have a general view of the scene with the results for every object i'm tracking.

I have taken a look at `boost::barrier`, that's a good start but I have no idea on how to gather results once I managed to stop all the threads at the end of the loop. Do I need an extra "gatherer" thread? I did my only course in parallel computing a few years ago so I'm a bit rusty in parallel things :) thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to stop the threads. Using some common multithreading technics like mutexes (`std::mutex` or `boost::mutex`) are fine to get that information.

You could keep some thread information about each running thread, e.g. some `struct ThreadInfo` and some `std::list<ThreadInfo> threads` or so where you keep track about all running threads.

Every `ThreadInfo` would have its own mutex. And you would put the information there which you want to have as part of your general view of the scene. While writing the data into the struct, of course you would lock/unlock the mutex. Locking a mutex is very fast (almost free) if it is not acquired by another thread so you don't loose much most of the time.

Then, in the main thread, where you are probably idling or where you want to display that information for the general view, every second or so, you would go through all `threads` and then read that information (of course before every read, you must lock/unlock the mutex).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. It's going to take a while to implement it since I'm having some troubles figuring out how to write the general view, but mutex is definitely the way to do it!